# Lagrange Multiplier - equation system

Tags: analysis, lagrange-multiplier

I'm trying to get the extrema of a function $x + y²$ with a constraint $2x² + y² = 1$ using Lagrange multipliers. The Lagrange function is $x + y² + \lambda (2x² + y² - 1)$. I have three partial derivatives:

1. $$1 + 4\lambda x = 0$$
2. $$2y + 2\lambda y = 0$$
3. $$2x² + y² - 1 = 0$$

My approach to solving these for x and y is as follows:

1. $$ 2\lambda = - 1 / 2x$$
2. $$ 2\lambda = - 2y / y = -2$$
   $$-1/2x = -2$$
   $$x = 1/4 $$
   Plugging into the constraint:
   $$2(1/4)² + y² = 1$$
   $$1 - 2/16 = y²$$
   $$y = \pm \sqrt{7/8}$$
   So I get 2 points $(1/4, -\sqrt{7/8})$ and $(1/4, \sqrt{7/8})$ which are the correct maxima. If I plug the equation [system into Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+4*l*x+%3D+0%2C+2y+%2B+2*l*y+%3D+0%2C+2x%C2%B2+%2B+y%C2%B2+-+1+%3D+0), I get two more solutions, which I understand are the minima. How do I get these two other solutions? I'm probably missing some edge case, but I'm not sure how else to solve the equation system.

Comment: Did you copy some wrong numbers? Your derivatives do not match with your original problem.

Comment: Right, sorry, I mixed up the pages while copying. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing
$$2\lambda = - 2y / y = -2$$
You lost the potential solution $y=0$. That would give you another answer.

When doing Lagrange multiplier problems, be careful about all the cases, especially when multiplying or dividing by a variable.